# Play store asking me to update third party library even after updating. Unable to upload app to play store

Tags: android, upload, google-play-console, appsflyer-android-sdk

I am using Appsflyer library in my project. Previously I was using version 5.0.0. Then I got this message when uploading a new version.

**The developer of AppsFlyer SDK (com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk) has reported version 5.0.0 as outdated. You must upgrade to a newer version (5.1.0+) before you can publish a new release to production.**

So I updated the version from 5.0.0 to 6.5.4. But I still get this message. I am unable to upload app to play store.

If you need any other information, please let me know through the comments section. I will update it here. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Make sure to sync your gradle config, then do a clean build

Comment: Wow. It worked. I tried "invalidate cache / restart" option. This didn't solve the problem. But cleaning the project solved the problem. I never expected that cleaning the project would solve the issue. . Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Before posting this question I tried "invalidate cache / restart" option. It didn't work. But after reading the comment from Pierre, I cleaned the project and tried again. Surprisingly it worked. Thank you Pierre.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a different library. even after removing the library still, issue came. and I was using `react native`. first tried with  `./gradlew clean` then `./gradlew build`. then it solved